Define lifecycle check (globally) to avoid redeployment of ALL resources if tags are changed
How to define lifecycle check to avoid redeployment of resources if tags are changed
When i am using:
terraform {
  required_version = ">=1.0"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "5.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = var.aws_region
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      # Ignore changes to tags, e.g. because a management agent
      # updates these based on some ruleset managed elsewhere.
      tags,
    ]
  }
}

I am getting error:
The block type name "lifecycle" is reserved for use by Terraform in a future version.

The ignore_changes should be set at the resource level, not the provider.
Example:
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-0c94855ba95c574c8"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags
    ]
  }
}

Some notes:

The arguments corresponding to the given attribute names are considered when planning a create operation, but are ignored when planning an update.
Instead of a list, the special keyword all may be used to instruct Terraform to ignore all attributes, which means that Terraform can create and destroy the remote object but will never propose updates to it.
Only attributes defined by the resource type can be ignored. ignore_changes cannot be applied to itself or to any other meta-arguments.


"Only attributes defined by the resource type can be ignored. ignore_changes cannot be applied to itself or to any other meta-arguments." This statement makes it clear why we can't use lifecycle argument inside provider.
Because provider is also a meta-Argument
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/resource-provider

Terraform doesn't redeploy resources if tags are added or removed.
